# MS Graph invite call does not work with objectId, only works with email

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

I am using [Drive item Invite endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0) to give an existing Azure AD user permissions on a one-drive(group one-drive) folder.

As per the  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driverecipient?view=graph-rest-1.0#remarks) we can either use email or objectId to grant permissions to a user, however when I am doing the call with objectId it fails with a 400 status code. If I do the call to give same user same permissions it works with email.

Following call works

URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!EbRqdRcmzk21wz2m9sBY5l3vh0lMNqtMhqojqNZdtV3jVfFqN25wQLgxqBe-lMFN/items/01EPSHROTVQE5PIMAEJBCZFOELF7FTKSYE/invite
```

Payload

```json
{"recipients":[{"email":"emailhere"}],
 "message":"Test message",
 "requireSignIn":true,
 "sendInvitation":false,
 "roles":["write"]}
```

Following call fails
URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!EbRqdRcmzk21wz2m9sBY5l3vh0lMNqtMhqojqNZdtV3jVfFqN25wQLgxqBe-lMFN/items/01EPSHROTVQE5PIMAEJBCZFOELF7FTKSYE/invite
```

Payload

```json
{"recipients":[{"objectId":"GUID"}],
 "message":"Test message",
 "requireSignIn":true,
 "sendInvitation":false,
 "roles":["write"]}
```

Following is the response from graph for the failed request with request-id.

```json
{
"error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "9b492f32-25ca-4a4d-bff1-bcf227fedab7",
        "date": "2019-02-28T10:41:14"
    }
  }
}
```